# Is it possible to initialize a random arrays of float32 or float16 without casting?

Tags: python, numpy

I see that there's np.random.uniform, but from the documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html

There is no argument for the data type, and by default it uses float.64 values.

I can not just cast the values to float32 or float16 because I would need to initialize the arrays at float64 and for the number of embeddings I am working with, this would use up all the ram in my enviroment.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this for float32 using the [random generator api](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.random.html#numpy.random.Generator.random), which does have a dtype parameter for the `random` method. Sadly this won't accept a float16.

```py
import numpy as np
size = [1, 100]
high = 50
low = 20
rand_array = np.random.default_rng().random(size, dtype=np.float32) * (high - low) + low
```

This code will make rand_array a float32 array of shape [1,100] with uniformly random numbers between 20 and 50.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to accept the need to cast, but do it in chunks that will not cause you to exceed the available memory.  Adjust the `chunk_size` to keep the time spent on explicit looping to a reasonably small amount while avoiding excessive memory usage.

```
import numpy as np

def uniform(minval, maxval, length,
              dtype=None, chunk_size=100000):
    
    answer = np.empty((length), dtype=dtype)
    for start in range(0, length, chunk_size):
        end = min(start + chunk_size, length)
        answer[start:end] = np.random.uniform(minval, maxval, end - start)

    return answer


x = uniform(2, 4, 1234567, dtype=np.float16)
print(x, x.dtype)
```